# Search string having spaces and special characters in it using C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, elasticsearch, couchbase, nest

I am looking for **ElasticSearch** nest query which will provide exact match on string having spaces in it **using C#**.

for example - I want to search for a word like 'XYZ Company Solutions'. I tried querystring query but it gives me all the records irrespective of search result. Also i read on the post and found that we have to add some mappings for the field. I tried 'Not_Analyzed' analyzer on the field but still it does not worked.

Here is my code of **C#**

```
**var indexDefinition = new RootObjectMapping
{
  Properties = new Dictionary<PropertyNameMarker, IElasticType>(),
  Name = elastic_newindexname
};
var notAnalyzedField = new StringMapping
{
  Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed
};
indexDefinition.Properties.Add("Name", notAnalyzedField);
objElasticClient.DeleteIndex(d => d.Index(elastic_newindexname));
var reindex = objElasticClient.Reindex<dynamic>(r => r.FromIndex(elastic_oldindexname).ToIndex(elastic_newindexname).Query(q => q.MatchAll()).Scroll("10s").CreateIndex(i => i.AddMapping<dynamic>(m => m.InitializeUsing(indexDefinition))));
ReindexObserver<dynamic> o = new ReindexObserver<dynamic>(onError: e => { });
reindex.Subscribe(o);**

**ISearchResponse<dynamic> ivals = objElasticClient.Search<dynamic>(s => s.Index(elastic_newindexname).AllTypes().Query(q => q.Term("Name","XYZ Company Solutions")));** //this gives 0 records

**ISearchResponse<dynamic> ivals1 = objElasticClient.Search<dynamic>(s => s.Index(elastic_newindexname).AllTypes().Query(q => q.Term(u => u.OnField("Name").Value("XYZ Company Solutions"))));** //this gives 0 records

**ISearchResponse<dynamic> ivals = objElasticClient.Search<dynamic>(s => s.Index(elastic_newindexname).AllTypes().Query(@"Name = 'XYZ Company Solutions'"));** //this gives all records having fields value starting with "XYZ"
```

Does anyone have a complete example or steps in C#?

Comment: Can you show us what the mapping for the index looks like? The first two c# queries generate the exact same elastic query. Are you sure your property in the index is called "Name", and not "name"? Elastic is case sensitive...

Comment: http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/put-mapping.html

Comment: yes I am sure that my property in the index called "Name".

Comment: See my answer on the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30022660/150568.  You need to make a `Refresh` call against the new index after the reindexing operation.

Comment: I have tried with this also but not getting any result.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get results back when running the query _outside_ of NEST?  

`POST /{elastic_newindexname}/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "Name": {
              "value": "XYZ Company Solutions"
           }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: No I am not getting result there also with term operator but with query string I am getting results but not exact match.

Comment: This one worked for me-

IIndicesOperationResponse result = null;

                if (!objElasticClient.IndexExists(elastic_indexname).Exists)
                {
                    result = objElasticClient.CreateIndex(elastic_indexname, c => c.AddMapping<dynamic>(m => m.Type("_default_").DynamicTemplates(t => t
                                                .Add(f => f.Name("string_fields").Match("*").MatchMappingType("string").Mapping(ma => ma
                                                    .String(s => s.Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)))))));
                }

Comment: I have created and mapped index using dynamic template and then did XDCR.So it worked for me.
while adding mapping Type "default" is suffixed and prefixed with underscore i am not able to mention here.
Thanks
Mukesh

Comment: This is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960168/elastic-search-search-string-having-spaces-and-special-characters-in-it-using-c