# C# String Equals comparison method fails for strings that have special characters in them

Tags: c#, string

I am currently comparing property values of type string using the string Equals method.

Example: `f.rfgmodel.Equals(model, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Now the problem I am running into is that for strings like ‘M&P9 Shield’ (a Firearm Model stored in my Accessories table in the DB), that has the ‘&’ symbol, the string Equals method doesn’t work.

Sadly, I cannot ignore the  ‘&’ symbol in such model values, so stripping out the ‘&’ symbol from existing DB records in the DB is not an option.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
[Route("filter/{pcategory}")]
        public IQueryable<AccessoryDto> GetAccessoryFilter(string pcategory = "", string model = "")
        {
            return db.Accessories.Where(f => (f.rfgacctype.Equals("holsters", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) & f.rfgparentcategory.Equals(pcategory, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) & f.rfgmodel.Equals(model, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            .Select(AsAccessoryDto);
        }
```

Example of my DB table:
[Accessory Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPS2G.jpg)

I have searched quite a bit and the few matches don’t have a solution, much less provide enough hints to lead me in the right direction in attempting to resolve my current problem.

Example 1: 
[C# String comparison fails for string having special character in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280155/c-sharp-string-comparison-fails-for-string-having-special-character-in-it)
In this particular thread, the user @Biki left a comment to the first answer, stating that the Equals method doesn’t work. This is true.

Example 2: This one didn’t help either: [Elastic Search-Search string having spaces and special characters in it using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960168/elastic-search-search-string-having-spaces-and-special-characters-in-it-using-c)

Please if anyone could help with a solution of provide hints pointing me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance. Much appreciated.

Comment: Does that `.Equals` call compile into SQL? To be sure, comparing strings containing the `&` is *not* going to be a problem.

Comment: I concur with @LasseV.Karlsen, I just ran some code because it was weird to me but that it would fail. The comparison succeeded where it needed to.

Comment: The '&' character has a special meaning both in HTML and in URL's so the `model` variable may have a different value than you expect.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Thanks, your suggestion lead me in the right path towards the cause of the problem and also in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem occurred from the url encoded value used for 'M&P9 Shield' when passed as a input parameter at my endpoint, i realized that the special character '&' was not being encoded properly, because the url encoded value was ending up as: http://localhost:56206/api/accessories/filter/pistols?caliber=9mm%20Luger%20(9x19%20Para)&model=M&P9%20Shield

instead of:
http://localhost:56206/api/accessories/filter/pistols?caliber=9mm%20Luger%20(9x19%20Para)&model=M%26P9%20Shield

I used this resource https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

So the '&' which is considered a unsafe ASCII character is encoded as '%26'

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the database collation? In my experience, most are set to

> Case Insensitive, Accent Sensitive

The following screenshot shows the database properties of one that I work with. The collation is the default, Latin1_General_CI_AS. CI = Case Insensitive, AS = Accent Sensitive. So "user" and "User" will be treated the same whereas "Como" and "Cómo" will be different.

[image: Database Collation]

So if that is the case, you can do without the call the `.Equals()` that specifies `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` because the db is doing that for you. Consider:

```
// Search db for items with an ampersand
var item = db.AssetMakes.Where(x => x.Name == "m & n").SingleOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"ID: {item?.AssetMakeID}, Name: {item?.Name}");
```

I used that code against my own database that has an item with that name, below is the output that I got. That may help in your case.

[image: Screenshot of above code's output]

Comment: Thanks @Fabulous, when i specified a value "M&P9 Shield" in the comparison statement, it gave results after the endpoint request.

Example: ... f.rfgmodel.Equals("M&P9 Shield", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            .Select(AsAccessoryDto);

When the input parameter 'model' is passed with the endpoint, the comparison fails.
Example: http://localhost:56206/api/accessories/filter/pistols?caliber=9mm%20Luger%20(9x19%20Para)&model=M&P9%20Shield

Comment: It appears that the url encoded value: http://localhost:56206/api/accessories/filter/pistols?caliber=9mm%20Luger%20(9x19%20Para)&model=M&P9%20Shield
is the culprit, since it's at this scenario that comparison doesn't work.

When i hard code the comparison value of 'M&P9 Shield', it works.